# User authentication mechanism for mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I'm upgrading my current website (c# + asp.net + webforms + sql-server-2008).

On my current website, I'm having user authentication mechanism based on "asp.net membership".

My upgraded version of the site using asp.net mvc4.

So, I need to make a choice:

1. To continue using asp.net membership in my mvc4 site (is that possible?)
2. Create a new authentication mechanism that works with mvc4.

What do you recommend to me? 
If you are choosing the first choice so please give me information on how to move the membership to mvc4. 
If you are choosing the second choice, so please give me another technology that similar to membership.

Thank you!

Comment: There is nothing involved in continuing to use your current membership setup. Its still ASP.NET.. Also, your question is primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVC4 templates favor the SimpleMembership provider but you can easily change the Web.Config and keep using your existing aspnetDb database. Even shared use (in a transition period) should be possible.

Authentication is largely the same, authorization has moved from the web.config to attributes on Controllers and Actions.

```
[Authorize] // deny '?'
class AccountController
{
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public ActionResult Register() { }

   ...
}
```